# Fabric + Virtualenvwrapper gives fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing

Tags: return, virtualenv, fabric, virtualenvwrapper

I have a fabric script to use virtualenvwrapper to create virtualenv, but after running mkvirutalenv  the fabric script complains about return code, see below

```
[localhost] run: export WORKON_HOME=/srv/www && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv james --no-site-packages --distribute
[localhost] Login password for 'james': 
[localhost] out: New python executable in james/bin/python
[localhost] out: Installing distribute...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
[localhost] out: Installing pip................done.


Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: export WORKON_HOME=/srv/www && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv james --no-site-packages --distribute
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /srv/www && export WORKON_HOME=/srv/www && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv james --no-site-packages --distribute"

Aborting.
```

Answer (score 1):

figured out that the position of --no-site-packages and --distribute has to be in front of the virtualenv name to return 0 such as

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute <name>
```